# Getting a tab from constructor for method in the same class in Java

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I'm a very beginner with java, and i have a problem with my program, i want to get a tab from constructor to method, but i have no idea how to do this, could anyone help me ?
Here is my code:

```
public class pascal4 {
    static int tab[][];
    public pascal4(int n){
     int tab[][]=new int[n+1][n+1];
       tab[0][0] = 1;
       for(int i = 1; i <n; i++)
       {
           tab[i][0] = 1;
           for(int j = 1; j <n; j++)
               tab[i][j] = tab[i-1][j] + tab[i-1][j-1];
       }

    } 


 public static int[][] wspolczynnik(int m){
    return tab;
 }
```

I want method wspolczynnik to return the tab from constructor to main, how can i do this ?

Comment: I hope they aren't teaching you to code like this in a class.

Comment: It's hard to tell just where you are with this.  Is the problem that you don't know how to have `main` use `wspolczynnik` at all, or is the problem that you're using it and it's returning `null` unexpectedly, or is it something else, or are you just so confused you don't really know what to ask?

Comment: You really should remove both `static` keywords from the code.  The point of calling a constructor is that it creates an object, and then initializes data that belongs to the object.  Your `static int tab` means there is only one `tab` instead of one for each object, so your constructor constructs an object but makes the object rather useless because you're not setting up any data in the object.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to stop declaring tab again inside your constructor (`int tab[][]=new int[n+1][n+1];`) and use the tab attribute from your class (`static int tab[][];`).

So `int tab[][]=new int[n+1][n+1];` should be just `tab=new int[n+1][n+1];` which means that you use the class attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
int tab[][]=new int[n+1][n+1];
```

to

```
tab[][]=new int[n+1][n+1];
```

This will use the class's `tab` instead of the constructor's `tab`.